# Netty vs Tornado by performance?

Tags: performance, netty, tornado

I try to stress test **WebSocketServer** under Netty and compare it with hello demo in **Tornado**.

Both receive and response a "hello world html" and I stress test by **Siege**.
They are run under exactly the same environment.

We expect native java should be faster than Tornado/Python. However, the result is:
Tornado/Python is about **2X faster than** Netty in term of no. of request handled per second.

Can anyone explain why native Java is slower?
Is the test correct?

Thanks

**JAVA**:  Transaction rate:             657.89 trans/sec
**Python**: Transaction rate:            1435.41 trans/sec

### JAVA WebSocketServer

```
public class WebSocketServer {

private final int port;

public WebSocketServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public void run() {
    // Configure the server.
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    // Set up the event pipeline factory.
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new WebSocketServerPipelineFactory());

    // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));

    System.out.println("Web socket server started at port " + port + '.');
    System.out.println("Open your browser and navigate to http://localhost:" + port + '/');
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port;
    if (args.length > 0) {
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } else {
        port = 8888;
    }
    new WebSocketServer(port).run();
}
```

}

### JAVA Message Handler

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    Object msg = e.getMessage();
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        handleHttpRequest(ctx, (HttpRequest) msg);
    } else if (msg instanceof WebSocketFrame) {
        handleWebSocketFrame(ctx, (WebSocketFrame) msg);
    }
}
private void handleHttpRequest(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest req) throws Exception {
    HttpResponse res = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
    // ChannelBuffer content = WebSocketServerIndexPage.getContent(getWebSocketLocation(req));
    ChannelBuffer content = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer( "<html><body>hello!</body></html>", CharsetUtil.US_ASCII);


    res.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    setContentLength(res, content.readableBytes());

    res.setContent(content);
    sendHttpResponse(ctx, req, res);
    return;

}

private void handleWebSocketFrame(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WebSocketFrame frame) {

    // Check for closing frame
    if (frame instanceof CloseWebSocketFrame) {
        handshaker.close(ctx.getChannel(), (CloseWebSocketFrame) frame);
        return;
    } else if (frame instanceof PingWebSocketFrame) {
        ctx.getChannel().write(new PongWebSocketFrame(frame.getBinaryData()));
        return;
    } else if (!(frame instanceof TextWebSocketFrame)) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("%s frame types not supported", frame.getClass()
                .getName()));
    }

    // Send the uppercase string back.
    String request = ((TextWebSocketFrame) frame).getText();
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug(String.format("Channel %s received %s", ctx.getChannel().getId(), request));
    }
    ctx.getChannel().write(new TextWebSocketFrame(request.toUpperCase()));
}

private static void sendHttpResponse(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest req, HttpResponse res) {
    // Generate an error page if response status code is not OK (200).
    if (res.getStatus().getCode() != 200) {
        res.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(res.getStatus().toString(), CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        setContentLength(res, res.getContent().readableBytes());
    }

    // Send the response and close the connection if necessary.
    ChannelFuture f = ctx.getChannel().write(res);
    if (!isKeepAlive(req) || res.getStatus().getCode() != 200) {
        f.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
}
```

### Python under Tornado

```
define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.write("Hello, world")


def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: Tornado uses `epoll` library which is written in C, and has small amount of code in python on top of it. May be Netty has it's own implementation for library like `epoll`, or something like this. BTW question is not constructive. Where code samples? Where your code deployment configurations? What answer you want to get?

Comment: code sample is added. As i explained in question, I want to know why native Java is slower than scripting python as webserver. Or any issue in my test.

Comment: @BillyHuiChiTat , because there are library written in C under tornado. If you will build big application with large amount of python code - it will become slower than Java.

Comment: @BillyHuiChiTa, what OS and version of Java are you running?